# Chrome adding white space to bottom of parallax page, firefox acts as expected

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, parallax

I have uploaded the current issue to [my homepage](http://dustwise.com).

When you scroll down to the bottom of the page, Chrome leaves a large white gap, seems to be 50% of the height of the final element?

This does not occur in Firefox and it looks as expected.

Relevant code snippets include:

App CSS:

```
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
perspective: 1px;
perspective-origin: 0 0;
```

Element CSS:

```
transform-origin: 0 0;
transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
height: 100vh;
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You do know that 100vh gives the element the height value of the browser/screen viewable area? I think your element content has less height than the viewable screen area and your height:100vh is setting it to have the full viewable screen height value so its adding the remaining amount as white space.

Comment: The internal element has a gradient applied to it with content centered, this is desired and functional. The issue only exists on Chrome where it seemingly extends beyond 100vh. I am able to scroll up past the extra white on the bottom and fit the 100vh element in the window.

I edited my post to correctly link to the page in question. Sorry about that!